# How to Enable Refence Transaction

Tags: paypal, braintree

we are using braintree sandbox sdk and integrate paypal sandbox for the paypal payment..

we are getting below error:-

errorMessage = "Authorization error --- REFUSED_MARK_REF_TXN_NOT_ENABLED:This merchant account is not permitted to create Merchant Initiated Billing Agreement";

does any one have idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which PayPal sandbox account have you configured your Braintree gateway with? How old is it?

PayPal sandbox accounts used to not have Mark Reference Transactions enabled by default, and you would need to contact PayPal MTS to ask them to enable it. Today, however, all new PayPal Business accounts created in sandbox will have this enabled by default. So, you can simply create a new sandbox PayPal Business account via https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts%2F , and use that new one to configure your Braintree gateway for sandbox mode

Answer (score 0):

It seems a PayPal merchant configuration problem. You are trying to make a payment that requires a billing agreement but your PayPal merchant account is not to able to accept this type of payment. Instead, If you are trying to make a one time payment then there is a integration problem. Integrate in what platform or framework?